# How to retrieve total number / count of records stored in Big Object?

Tags: query, big-object, count

Even this seemingly easy task is impossible to do.

For some reason, even when I loaded millions of data into Big Object, it somehow isn't reflected in

> Setup > Storage Usage

[image]

Given sometimes it shows or doesn't show on storage usage, there has to be another way to find out how many records is uploaded into big object.

So I tried via workbench (even including index) but no luck:

[image]

Comment: note: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195147/what-is-the-big-object-actual-size; did you try async soql to get count?

Comment: Async SOQL requires you to insert/upsert into a custom object so I don't understand what you mean. Plus I got the error : No-argument COUNT() is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How I tackled this :**

1. Creating a Custom Object.
2. Create at least a custom field of Number type to hold the Record count (e.g. BigObjectCount__c)
3. No need to include INDEX fields in Async SOQL
4. Go Workbench > Async SOQL Query
5. Input the Async SOQL resembling something like "SELECT COUNT(external_id__c) from big_object__b". (*"SELECT COUNT(id) from big_object__b" will not work whatsoever*)
6. Operation type = INSERT

   a) Target Object = *custom object from step 1*

   b) Map source fields to target fields : expr0 to BigObjectCount__c

   c) **Submit**

Answer (score 0):

With or without argument, Count() is not supported for big objects. You would need to leverage Async SOQL which as you stated, requires a dump into a custom object to use the additional SOQL commands:

Big Objects SOQL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_querying.htm

Big Objects Async SOQL: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/async_query_reference.htm

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you giving me this general answer but this won't cut it for an accepted answer